# NodeJS, FB oauth/authorize JSONPARSE error

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get facebook access token and verification code with [facebook node SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb#installing-facebook-node-sdk).

Code snippet:

```
var FB = require('fb');

FB.api('oauth/authorize'
, {client_id:x, redirect_uri:'http://localhost:9999/callback/'}
, function (res) {
    console.log('....');
    if(!res || res.error) {
        console.log(!res ? 'unknown err' : 'err:' + JSON.stringify(res));
    }
})
```

x is the actual app ID. The code always throws me error:

```
{"error":{"code":"JSONPARSE","Error":{}}}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You should log error with error.stack to see what error is it.

```
var FB = require('fb');

FB.api('oauth/authorize'
, {client_id:x, redirect_uri:'http://localhost:9999/callback/'}
, function (res) {

    if(!res) {
        console.error( new Error("Unknow error occur");
    } else if(res.error){
        console.error(res.error.stack);
    } else {
        console.log(res);
        // Continue
    }
});
```